# Worklight: Any impact of google ending support for android eclipse tools

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Environment:

- Worklight 6.1.0.2
- Dojo 1.9.4
- Eclipse Juno

We have developed a hybrid mobile application using worklight 6.1. We use eclipse juno to develop the app. As Google has announced to end support for android eclipse tools, I would like to know, if there will be any impact on the way we develop the app. Will there be any problem while publishing the app (built using worklight) to Google Play store ?

I guess, we will not be able to use eclipse to run/debug the app now.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

It should not be an issue as you can still run your Android app in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There will not be a problem with publishing applications to Google Play Store.

You can configure Eclipse > Preferences > MobileFirst (or Worklight) with the location of your Android Studio installation. This will enable you to right-click on the application folder and select Run As > Android Studio project, which will launch the project in Android Studio.

The only limitation is that Worklight-generated projects are not compatible with Gradle, so you should not migrate to Gradle (Android Studio will suggest this). If you do migrate, the next time you build the project in Worklight Studio in Eclipse the native project that will be generated will again be non-Gradle...